# How to create an alert for expiring AD Users

Tags: powershell, active-directory

this is my first try in Powershell and I have to say I have no Idea what I am doing.

So I want to create a Script, that when it runs send an E-Mail to an Admin with a list of ADUsers who are going to expire within the next 30 Days.

This was my first try to get the Users as an output but it doesn't work and I have no Idea why not. So I can't go on and do the Mail-Send thing. I didn't find anything similar on the internet too.

`Get-ADUser -Filter 'enabled -eq $true' -SearchBase "CN=Users, DC=mydomain, DC=de" -Properties $var=((get-date).AddDays(30)) -le AccountExpirationDate | Select-Object distinguishedName, AccountExpirationDate`

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user property `accountExpires` equals to 0 or 9223372036854775807, then the account never expires.
To get a list of accounts that are expiring within a certain number of days, you an do:

```
$refDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(30)
$expiringUsers = Get-ADUser -Filter 'Enabled -eq $true' -SearchBase "CN=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=de" -Properties AccountExpirationDate, accountExpires | 
    Where-Object {($_.accountExpires -gt 0 -and $_.accountExpires -ne 9223372036854775807) -and ($_.AccountExpirationDate -le $refDate)} |
    Select-Object Name, DistinguishedName, AccountExpirationDate
```

Next, you need to send this to an admin by email.
There are various ways of doing this of course, below example sends the result as CSV attachment.

```
# don't send mail if there are no expiring users found
if ($expiringUsers.Count) {
    # write the results to csv file
    $outFile = Join-Path -Path $env:TEMP -ChildPath ('{0:yyyy-MM-dd}_ExpiringUsers.csv' -f (Get-Date))
    $expiringUsers | Export-Csv -Path $outFile -NoTypeInformation

    # use splatting for cmdlets that take a lot of parameters
    $mailParams = @{ 
        SmtpServer  = 'smtp.fabrikam.com'
        From        = 'troi@fabrikam.com'
        To          = 'admin@fabrikam.com'
        Subject     = 'Expiring user accounts'
        Body        = 'Please find the list of expiring user accounts in the attachment'
        Attachments = $outFile
        # See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage
        # for more parameters you might want to use
    } 

    Send-Mailmessage @mailParams
    Write-Host "$($expiringUsers.Count) user accounts are set to expire within the next 30 days. An email has been sent."
}
else {
    Write-Host 'No user accounts are set to expire within the next 30 days'
}
```

<sup>`Get-ADUser` by default returns these properties: `DistinguishedName`,`Enabled`,`GivenName`,`Name`,`ObjectClass`,`ObjectGUID`,`SamAccountName`,`SID`,`Surname` and `UserPrincipalName`.
Property `AccountExpirationDate` is the value of property `accountExpires` converted to local time.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

To select users you need do like this

```
Get-ADUser -Filter 'enabled -eq $true' -SearchBase "CN=Users, DC=mydomain, DC=de" -Properties AccountExpirationDate| 
Where-Object {($_.Accountexpirationdate -le (get-date).AddDays(30)) -and ($_.Accountexpirationdate -ne $null)}
```

First you must select property what you want, then you piping your object to `Where-Object` and filtering your property. When you filter it you must check that field is not null because users with unlimited expiration have this field value `$null`, and your user field `$_.Accountexpirationdate` must be lesser or equal currentdate+30 days.
You can select needed fields after that and save you result to variable.Then you can send it via email.